# Adding data to PostgreSQL via form. Add fails if variable null/empty, how do I prevent this?

Tags: php, postgresql, variables, sql-insert

I'm adding data to a PostgreSQL database via a PHP form. It all feels a bit sketchy. My main concern is that; in the event of a variable being null/empty the add fails. How do I prevent this?

The simplified code is like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$movie = $_POST['movie'];
$query = "INSERT INTO data.base(name, movie) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $movie . "')";
$result = pg_query($query);
if ( $result ) {
    echo 'Thanks';
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

So if the `$movie` variable is null/empty the whole add fails.

I could do something like this I suppose:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
if ( ! $name ) {
    $name = '0';
}
```

But I'd rather keep the cell empty as opposed to inserting false data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using PHP7+ try this: `$name = $_POST['name'] ?? "undefined";`

Comment: I'm on 7.0.1, so this **is** an option, I shall do some testing. Thank you. Do you know that `undefined` allows the INSERT to happen?

Comment: `"undefined"` is just a default string if `$_POST['name']` is empty. It can be anything. I offered a string because i don't know your `data.base.name` column. [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: Oh okay, so I'd still be inserting dummy data?

Comment: Validation is complex monster.. Firstly try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Comment: It's not really a validation issue. Some of the variables are actually coming from an API and are added at the time of submission. However the API is unreliable, so if it fails to return data I'd rather the core info is submitted rather than the whole thing fail.

Comment: Oh i see. Than set name column to nullable, and default value to null. Use my first comment, but you must overwrite “undefined” to null

Comment: Thanks for all your help, so I'd do this for the name field for instance?
 `$name = $_POST['name'] ?? null;`

Answer (score 0):

**PHP 7+** is required for my solution.

If your `name` and `movie` column can be null, and devault value is `null` you can do something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? null;
$movie = $_POST['movie'] ?? null;
$query = "INSERT INTO data.base(name, movie) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $movie . "')";
$result = pg_query($query);
if ( $result ) {
    echo 'Thanks';
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

unfortunatelly it will be an empty row in you table.

But if you don't want junk rows, do something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? false;
$movie = $_POST['movie'] ?? false;

if ( $name and $movie ) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO data.base(name, movie) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $movie . "')";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    echo 'Thanks';
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

I recommend you to escaping the inputs.